# Scrapy: How to recrawl a page after some time?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Being lazy, I'm trying to use scrapy instead of implementing my own scraping service using celery+requests (been there, done that). Let's say I have a list of N pages that I like to monitor. After retrieving page X and reading its content, I want to tell the system to rescan it sometime later (depending on its content), say once two hours have passed.

Is such a thing possible with Scrapy?

Comment: You should keep "marked for update" URLs somewhere, anyway. The first thing coming into my mind is to keep the list of items to recrawl as a property on a spider class (if it runs "forever" and doesn't exclude already parsed URLs) and manage it during parsing.

Comment: Another option is to keep it in the database (or whereever are you pipelining crawled items) by adding a bool flag. Then, in spider's `__init__` you can read urls marked for recrawling from the database and set `start_urls` for the spider. Ugly? Definitely.

Comment: Alexander, this will not give me the "scan within X hours" feature. I guess it's not possible after all...

Comment: yup, I don't think it's available in Scrapy out of the box. You can hook it up on a cron job, for example..